# How to set threshold above or below which the signal turns zero

Tags: simulink

In simulink, I have a signal. Sometimes it is positive but sometimes it is negative. When the signal is positive, I want to turn it to zero when it is above a specific threshold. Similarly, when the signal is negative, I want to turn it to zero when it is below a specific threshold. Can you please let me know how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Is this to be a 'window detector', i.e. output HIGH iff signal is in the range (+threshold1, -threshold2)?   Or do you want 'it' to turn to zero, meaning shorting the signal to ground?

Answer (score 2):

Begin with a window comparator: -

[image]

The one above works with a positive supply rail but is easily reconfigured for a split rail supply that allows the full negative and positive input range desired.

So, you have a positive logic output signal from the window comparator that tells you your input signal is not too positive and not too negative. If the input rises too high or too low, the logic output drops to 0 volts (or minus voltage for a split rail supply) indicating your signal should be clamped to 0 volts.

Use the above logic output and an analogue switch to disconnect your input signal from your "real" output when the input is "out of range". You will probably choose to convert the logic signal from the window comparator to something more suitable for the enable pin on the analogue switch such as 5 volt logic levels: -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In logic we call this Not Exclusive OR or XNOR and a simple RC delay will produce this when biased to Vdd/2 on one side of an XNOR = XOR & INV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frOsyH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In analog a 4 diode bridge does this when limited to logic levels.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flxQCE.png)</sup>

For analog comparators, it can just be a comparator with hysteresis or x% positive feedback by Rf/Rin ratio to in+ then XOR with delay output.

These are all called frequency doublers too, since 2 pulses per cycle.

There's a few other ways too depending on all I/O specs.

Obviously you want a negative logic zero crossing detector with some pulse width=x% of cycle.

Since this is more of a general solution "comment" rather than an explicit answer, do me a favour and **define all I/O specs in as much numerical detail and tolerance as you need.**

"sometimes positive" is vague